# How to add compass/utilities to the load paths (compass + sass + netbeans)

Tags: sass, compass-sass, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to use the sass plugin of Netbeans, my .scss file require the compass library. It work well from the commad line:

```
compass compile
```

but in the Netbeans IDE I get the following error:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/utilities.
```

The load paths listed don't show the compass library.

How can I include the compass library to make the .scss compile in Netbeans?

Mac OSX, Netbeans 7.2, SASS 3.1.20, Compass 0.12.2

Answer (score 0):

If you are using netbeans 4.7 and the builtin css compiler you can add --compass to the sass commandline options.  Make sure you have ruby in your PATH.  Also make sure you have your config.rb in the root of the project.